# How to redirect url from public class in mvc4 razor

Tags: c#, razor

I want to redirect page after sending the mail to active page. I have created a Model SendMail and Controller

In Model SendMail.cs I'm fetching data:

```
public class SendMail
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller SendMail:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult SendMail()
 {
   return View();
 }
 [HttpPost]
 public string SendMail(SendMail SendMail)
 {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SendMail.Name) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SendMail.Email) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SendMail.Comment))
  {
    //Sending Mail SMPT Setting                    
    return Url;
  }
  else
  return Url;
  }
```

It works Perfectly but I don't understand How can I redirect Active Url in public string SendMail class after Sending Mail.

before sending mail
[before sending mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUt8R.png)
after Sending mail
[after sending mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV6Wd.png)

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SendMail(SendMail SendMail)
 {
  if (...)
  {
    //Sending Mail SMPT Setting    
    return RedirectToRoute(URL);
  }
  else
  return RedirectToRoute(URL);
}
```

I think you need to change string by ActionResult to be able to redirect.
I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: I want to call URL of that page I'm active how can i read it via java script and send it to there in RedirectToRoute(URL);